# Custom Domain Name - Server not found Google App Engine and Google Apps

Tags: google-app-engine, domain-name-system, subdomain, g-suite, cname-record

I have integrated my domain at Google Apps with Google App Engine. I added www.myDomain.com to google app,it was working correctly and pointing to my application at appEngine, but now it doesn't direct to appengine, although myApp.appspot.com is working properly. Do you have any idea what cause this problem?

Edit:Extra Info

Initially sites were active, I deleted www from there and add it to appEngine it worked. I deployed different versions in app engine, and returned to previous version (by the way I didn't touch to Apps), suddenly www.myDomain.com and others like test.myDomain.com started to do not work.
http://docs.myDomain.com also does not work

Same Topic:
http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/7541a94c0d5895b7

Errors I got:

Firefox: The connection was reset

Chrome: This webpage is not available.

IE: Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage.

Comment: Did you add the correct DNS entries in the control panel of your domain provider? Keep in mind that DNS changes to your domain can take up to 24 hours to filter through to the DNS server used by your internet connection.

Comment: I registered my domain from google, do I assume that it works automatically because I checked that and for Cname "www", ghs.google.com. was already there.

Comment: Sounds lik  e either a transient glitch with ghs.google.com or possibly a DNS problem.  What is the exact error you are seeing?

Comment: I have added errors to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you possibly living in Turkey? Using Turkish ISPs? Because ghs.l.google.com is blocked currently in Turkey.

Answer (score 0):

Have you now, or previously, enabled Google Sites? If so, try enabling sites (if it is not already), setup an entry for 'www', then delete the 'www' entry from sites.

Comment: I read about that from forums and I tried it, but it didn't help. Is this a bug?

Comment: Yeah, this issue pops up periodically.